# Comparing information from an API call and an Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, loops, match

I'm trying to compare the results of an API call to an existing array. Basically, I want to make a function that will loop through the array, then loop through the data from the API to see if there's a match.

Here's an example of the array I'm working with

```
let array = [ { 
"name": "student1",
"id": 134},
{
"name": "student2",
"id": 135}, 
{
"name": "student3",
"id": 136}
]
```

Here's my function in JavaScript/jQuery

```
function getData() {
$.ajax({
        url: "www.studentapi.com",
        dataType: "json"
    }).done(function(data) {
console.log(data)
}
}
```

The data I get back looks kind of like this:
[ {

```
"id": 134,
"score": 45},
{ 
"id": 138,
"score": 67},
{ 
"id": 139,
"score": 34}
]
```

I'm trying to find a way to find the matching ids in the array and in the data. So far I've tried:

```
for (let j =0; j < data.length; j++) {
    if (array[j]["id"] === data[j].id) {
        console.log("we have a match!")
    }
    else {
        console.log("not a match!");
    }
}
```

But this isn't working. Am I doing something incorrectly over here?

Comment: corrected it! still isnt working though

Comment: With that sort of logic you are assuming that each corresponding index will bring the same exact information. That means, say you are in j=3, you are assuming that index j in data and array hold the same info. I guess what you are trying to do is check if the IDs in the first array match at least one value that is coming in the second (the one coming from the json request).

Comment: It's working when I try it. You get one `we have a match!` for the first object and two `not a match` for the other ones, as expected, since `135!==138` and `136!==139`. 

One potential issue with your solution is that it works only if the objects are in the exact same sequence between both arrays.

Comment: @Benjamin Yeah, that's the issue and that's what I commented above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use find on an array to find an element that matches some conditional.

The below logic also uses arrow functions, but could be changed to use normal `function(){}`

```js
let array = [
  {
    "name": "student1",
    "id": 134
  },
  {
    "name": "student2",
    "id": 135
  },
  {
    "name": "student3",
    "id": 136
  }
];

let data = [
  {
    "id": 134,
    "score": 45
  },
  {
    "id": 138,
    "score": 67
  },
  {
    "id": 139,
    "score": 34
  }
];

let studentData = array.map(student=>{
  student.data = data.find(record=>record.id === student.id) || {};
  return student;
});

console.log(studentData);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the javascript filter function.

```
let matchingStudents = array.filter(student => {
    return data.find(jsonData => student.id === jsonData.id);
});
```

There matchingStudents would hold all students present in the first array that are present in the second.

If you are wondering about the syntax, this is ES6. Next generation javascript. To write it in old javascript it'd be:

```
var matchingStudents = array.filter(function(student){
     return data.find(function(jsonData){ return student.id === jsonData.id});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To specifically answer your question *Am I doing something incorrectly over here?*

Your search code here assumes that `array` and `data` will contain the exact same ids in the exact same order:

```
for (let j =0; j < data.length; j++) {
    if (array[j]["id"] === data[j].id) {
```

Based on the sample data you provided, this isn't the case; you can't always compare `array[j]` to `data[j]` to match ids because (for example) it's possible you need to match `array[4]` to `data[6]`.

One solution to this problem is to use a nested loop:

```
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
    if (array[i].id === data[j].id) {
```

This way you'll compare every entry in `array` to every entry in `data` when looking for matches.  (This is similar to what the solutions suggesting `array.map` and `data.find` are doing, with some smart early-out behavior.)

Another approach would be to sort both lists and step forward through them together.

```js
let array = [
  { "id": 134, "name": "student1" },
  { "id": 139, "name": "student2" },
  { "id": 136, "name": "student3" }
];

let data = [
  { "id": 134, "score": 45 },
  { "id": 138, "score": 67 },
  { "id": 139, "score": 34 }
];

array.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id)
data.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id)
let data_i = 0;
for (let array_i = 0; array_i < array.length; array_i++) {
  while (data[data_i].id < array[array_i].id) {
    data_i++;
  }

  if (data_i < data.length && data[data_i].id === array[array_i].id) {
    console.log(`Matched ${array[array_i].name} to score ${data[data_i].score}`);
  } else {
    console.log(`No match found for ${array[array_i].name}`);
  }  
}
```